# Can't store arguments as arrays and print them in C

Tags: c, arrays, command, arguments, storage

I have the program (let's call it pr), and I can't understand what happens that suddenly I get an error when everything seem to be right. In terminal, I type:

```
./pr 2011-11-01/03:20
```

and I want to store into 2 arrays the date and the time. The date in the array aa == "2011-11-01" and the time in bb == "03:20" and at the end print them. So, I wrote the code below:

EDIT: The new code with `malloc()` below:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
int j=0, i=0;
char *aa = malloc(10*sizeof(char));
char *bb = malloc(5*sizeof(char));

while ( j!=10 ) {
    aa[j] = *(argv[1]+j);
j++;
}
j++;
while ( *(argv[1]+j) != '\0' ) {
    bb[j-11] = *(argv[6]+j++);
}
printf("%s and %s", aa, bb);
}
```

But the output of the above is:`2011-11-01Y and 03:20` where Y is a random character every time...

End of edit...

Old one below:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *aa, *bb; int j=0, i=0;
    while ( *(argv[1]+j) != '/' )
    {
        aa[j] = *(argv[6]+j++);
    }
    j++;

    while ( *(argv[1]+j) != '\0' )
    {
        bb[i++] = *(argv[1]+j++);
    }
    printf("%s %s", aa, bb);
}
```

The code above doesn't work for some reason, but when I write:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *aa; int j=0;
    while ( *(argv[1]+j) != '/' )
    {
        aa[j] = *(argv[1]+j++);
    }
    printf("%s", aa);
}
```

or

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *bb; int j, i=0;
    j=11; printf("%d", j);
    while ( *(argv[1]+j) != '\0' )
    {
        bb[i++] = *(argv[1]+j++);
    }
    printf("%s", bb);
}
```

it works fine! Does anybody know why is this happening?

Comment: In the first one, you increment `j` outside the loop.

Comment: You're writing to unitialized pointers(aa and bb). You need to allocate storage for them before writing in the loops.

Comment: `aa` and `bb` are not arrays. They are pointers.

Comment: Use malloc to allocate memory to aa and bb .

Comment: I count at least three different invokes of *undefined behavior* in this code, including (but not limited to) writing to both `aa` and `bb` while as indeterminate pointers, and [mashing a sequence point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points) violation with things like `a[j] = <<something>>j++;`

Comment: Also, `argv[6]` in your first example is well out of bounds. The last component of the `argv` array is `argv[1]`, which contains the string `2011-11-01/03:20`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answers! But if I use malloc, something else also goes wrong when the string is printed...

Comment: In the code with `malloc()`, you allocate 10 bytes to store a string of 11 characters (you are forgetting the null byte at the end of the string).  Similarly for the time.  In the code that 'works', you got unlucky — they should be crashing too.

Answer (score 1):

You should do

```
char *aa = malloc(11*sizeof(char));
```

to account for the \0 character and after the first loop you should write

```
aa[j] = '\0'
```

Basically, you are not ending the aa string with a \0 so the printf does not stop
at the final character and thus you have a random one afterwards.